# Jquery function not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following php page and for some reason the jquery function i have doesn't work, can someone please help me with this, by it doesn't work, i mean when i click the button it doesn't do anything:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function CalcSubTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            $("input[name *='Amount']").each(function () {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            });
            $("input[name ='SubTotal']").val(total.toFixed(2));

    }
    </script>


<form method="post" >
            <tr>
                <td>Payments Made Today:</td>
                <td>$<input type="text" name="FirstAmount" value="00.00">CC</td>
                <td>$<input type="text" name="SecondAmount" value="00.00">CHK</td>
                <td>$<input type="text" name="ThirdAmount" value="00.00">CASH</td>
                <td>$<input type="text" name="SubTotal"   value="00.00"></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="button" onclick="CalcSubTotal();" value="Click me" />
</form>
```

Comment: did you include the jquery? With firebug (firefox) you can see the error when you click

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zy945/

Comment: you were right, there was a misspelling in the  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>, i fixed it and it worked, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that you have referenced the jQuery library in your document. Usually, we add it within the `<head>` tags, like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Or, as a further example, if you also wish to use features of the jQueryUI library:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you including jQuery? I loaded it then tried your code and it worked. For more helo use F12 (Developer Tools) in Chrome.